# Have 48 Hours difference, converting C# Ticks to Java Timestamp

Tags: java, c#, datetime, calendar, gregorian-calendar

According to MSDN, `System.DateTime.Ticks` "represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 (0:00:00 UTC on January 1, 0001, in the Gregorian calendar)".

There's a internal field in `DateTime`, `UnixEpoch`, with the value `621355968000000000L` which should correspond to the Unix Epoch (midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC). (We can get the same value from `new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0,System.DateTimeKind.Utc);`.)

I'm trying to create a `Date` in Java based on a C# ticks value:

Here's a simple Java example to reproduce the problem:

```
    //C# System.DateTime.UnixEpoch = 621355968000000000;

    //Java code:
    //before Unix Epoch, in milliseconds
    Date date = new Date(-621355968000000000L / 10000);

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    df.format(date); // 0001-01-03 00:00:00.000 +0000
```

Is there a kind of gap in Gregorian calendar, which is taken into account only by one of platforms?

Comment: What's `System.DateTime.UnixEpoch`? I don't see that in MSDN.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I think all of the code above is Java; the OP is taking a value they've gotten from C#, and trying to create a Java `Date` from it.

Comment: There is data exchange between C# & Java platforms. So, need to understand which platform calendar have "specific" behaviour.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder System.DateTime.UnixEpoch is internal const long. We can get same value calculating by new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0,System.DateTimeKind.Utc)

Comment: @vlasov - have you tried using something like Jodatime or the java 8 time API to create a DateTime at 0:00:00 UTC on January 1, 0001, and comparing its value to `-621355968000000000L / 10000`?

Comment: @AndyTurner Same with GregorianCalendar. Setting calendar with 01-01-01 also produce a 48hours diff. Haven't try Joda.

Comment: @vlasov seems to work for me in Jodatime: `System.out.println(new DateTime(-621355968000000000L / 10000, DateTimeZone.UTC));` => `0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`

Comment: Java 8's `java.time` [works correctly, too](http://ideone.com/VKPDuR).

Answer (score 1):

It seems Java Date uses the Julian Calendar for dates when that calendar was used while C#, in this case, uses Gregorian Calendar back before there was one. By default Joda-Time also uses the Gregorian Calendar back in time.

This seems to work but there's probably a better way.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(-621355968000000000L / 10000);
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, dt.getYear());
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, dt.getMonthOfYear() - 1);
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dt.getDayOfMonth());
gc.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
gc.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
gc.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
gc.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

Date date = gc.getTime();
```